# Cython 2-D numpy array of mixed types to void**

Tags: c++, numpy, cython

I have a 2-D Numpy array of mixed types which I have declared to be of dtype = 'object' which is to my knowledge the most generic dtype I can use.

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3],['Six','Ten','Rodger']], dtype = 'O')
```

In a Cython wrapper I need to convert this 2-D array to a void** array in order to satisfy a function signature on the C++ side. I'm aware that because I've selected `dtype = 'O'` the allocated memory will be larger than I need to be and this will not be passed to the function properly in its current form.

The types of the arrays in the second dimension are always consistent and
I have a way of knowing from other information passed to the data structure what each of these types should be. I then convert each of the secondary arrays using `numpy.asarray` and set the corresponding `void*`

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3],['Six','Ten','Rodger']], dtype = 'O')
num_entries = arr.shape[1]
cdef void** ptr_arr = <void**> malloc(arr.shape[0]*sizeof(void*))
cdef np.ndarray this_arr

cdef DataType type

for i in range(num_entries):
    type = get_type(tags[i]) # this is where the data's dtype is collected
    ### i = 0 -> dtype is int  i = 1 -> dtype is 'S6' ###
    this_arr = np.asarray(arr[i], dtype = type)
    ptr_arr[i] = <void*> this_arr.data
```

...but this doesn't seem to be working based on the results I'm getting back from the c++ function call.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

ADDITION: I've gotten this method to work for mixed dtypes of `int32` and `float64` but it doesn't seem to play well with strings for some reason. Could it have something to do with proper padding of null characters in Numpy vs. C?

Comment: I don't know cython, so this may be completely off, but are you sure references to all the `this_arr`s are kept?

Comment: Do you know what what type of data your C function casts the `void*`s into? It does actually need to match.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I wondered the same thing, but I think they are. Printing the `void*`'s as `char*`'s to the console seems to indicate they they are kept anyways :)

@DavidW the C function should only cast the `void*`'s into appropriate types on the other side of the function, but it's hard to know what's going on there for sure.. part of what makes this particularly difficult. What I do know is that this method works for combinations of python type `int` and `float` but not for strings for some reason.

Comment: Again, I'm just guessing, but looking at the representation of strings in a string array using `.tostring` for example the longest strings clearly are not zero-terminated. So I agree with your suspicion that the problem may lie with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

As constructed this is not an array of arrays, or a list of lists, or anything like that.  It is a (2,3) array, where each element is a pointer.

```
In [1]: arr = np.array([[1,2,3],['Six','Ten','Rodger']], dtype = 'O')
In [2]: arr
Out[2]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       ['Six', 'Ten', 'Rodger']], dtype=object)
In [3]: arr.shape
Out[3]: (2, 3)
In [4]: arr[0,:]
Out[4]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)
....
```

Those pointers point to integers or strings elsewhere in memory.

It looks like you are trying to do, in Cython, the equivalent of

```
In [16]: a2=np.zeros((2,),object)
In [17]: a2[...] =[arr[0].astype(int), arr[1].astype(str)]
In [18]: a2
Out[18]: 
array([array([1, 2, 3]),
       array(['Six', 'Ten', 'Rodger'], 
      dtype='<U6')], dtype=object)
```

Sorry if I stating the obvious. I'm trying to come to speed with `cython`, but don't intend to get much into the C++ part.  And without the rest of your Cython code I can't run it and see for myself what is wrong.  We just have to take your word that something vague is wrong.